# Traefik doesn't pick TLS certificates secrets from the ingress definition in Kubernetes

Tags: https, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

When I only add the TLS secret to the Ingress, Traefik serves it's default certificate.

```
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
    ....
  tls:
  - secretName: ingress-mgt-server-keys
```

Only when I mount the secret and add below parameter, does Traefik start serving the real certificate.

> entryPoints.https.tls.certificates

**Are TLS secrets to be define in both Ingress and Ingress-controller**? This forces me to repeat the keys as secrets to all the ingress namespaces as well as the ingress-controller namespace.

[Update]: Traefik has RBAC to read secrets from the target namespace.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The TLS Secret isn't needed to be set up in the target (ingress) namespaces.

Only the ingress controller namespace needs the TLS Secret.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, that does not seem to be the case.

https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#add-a-tls-certificate-to-the-ingress

`In addition to the modified ingress you need to provide the TLS certificate via a Kubernetes secret in the same namespace as the ingress.`